# Google Script: Forward received mail-attachements in new Mails

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

I want to forward certain mails which flagged as star. I want to only send the plain body (not the HTML body) and also forward the originally attached files if any.

My current code looks like this:

```
function getMailsAndForward() {
  var thread, subject, body_PLAIN, emails, i;

  emails = GmailApp.search("in:SomeLabel AND in:starred");  
  var count = emails.length;

  if (count == 0)
    return; 

  for (i=0; i<count; i++) {    
    if (emails[i]) 
    {
      thread     = emails[i].getMessages()[0];
      subject    = "[AUTO-FORWARD] " + thread.getSubject();
      body_PLAIN = thread.getPlainBody(); 

      GmailApp.sendEmail("", subject, body_PLAIN, {"bcc": "xx@yy.com, fewmore@here.com"});

      // Unstar Mail... 
      GmailApp.unstarMessage(thread); 
    }
  }
}
```

I found a few solutions already online on how to extract attachements from received mails to GoogleDrive for example, and also on how to attach GoogleDrive Files to newly created mails.

**BUT before going this route/way, I want to ask:**
Is there any easier way without needing to save the attachements to a file in GoogleDrive beforehand? Would be handy...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modification?

You can retrieve the attachment files using [`getAttachments()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getAttachments()) as an array included blobs. The array with blobs is used for [`GmailApp.sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)). By this, it is not required to save the attachment files to Google Drive as files.

#### From :

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("", subject, body_PLAIN, {"bcc": "xx@yy.com, fewmore@here.com"});
```

#### To :

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("", subject, body_PLAIN, {"bcc": "xx@yy.com, fewmore@here.com", "attachments": thread.getAttachments()});
```

#### Note :

- In this modified script, if there are no attachment files, the mail without attachment files is sent.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Perfect, didnt know it's working like this. awesome, thanks!

Comment: @tim Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.